# IIS Local Server Setup

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web apllication that I want to test on other machines such as smartphones,tablets etc.How can I make changes to the code on my computer and see the build on other devices?

Comment: Do you want to run the code of the application on the device or merely a browser on the smartphones and tablets?

Comment: I want to run the code and debug the code on my PC and run it on tablets to see how changes in code affect the application on the tablet.

Comment: Then this seems like a networking issue as it should be relatively easy to run a browser on the device pointing at your machine.

Answer (score 0):

what OS/IIS version are you running?  In any case point the "Default Web Site" to the root of your web project and make sure it's bound to port 80.  You should be able to access it by "http://[machinename]" or "http://[ipaddress]".  Make sure your devices are connected to your LAN. I've noticed that Android will not resolve the machine name but ip address should work.

Comment: I'm running Windows 8,Visual Studio 2012 and IIS version 6.2.I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I get this error:The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.

Comment: make sure that your IIS users have access to the project directory.  If using anonymous in IIS, which should be the default.  Then add the group IIS_IUSRS (this is the Win7 group, may have changed in Win8).

Comment: How do I add that?Please help,I'm doing this for the first time!

Comment: it's folder permissions on the project folder.  I have not used Win8 so i'm not sure how much of this will apply: Right click on the root of your web site, go to "Properties", go to "Security" tab, add the "IIS_IUSRS" group (or whatever Win8 calls it), should default to Read/Execute permission.  do an IISRESET just be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

If you can hook the machines into a local area network that is the same as your web server, then that is the easiest solution.  For example, if they can share the same Wifi connection then it may be possible for your tablet or smartphone to access your web server through its local IP.

On the other hand, if you don't want to have that network dependency, you'll need a public IP that will work for the tablets, smartphones, etc. to see the site.

Comment: I have the devices on the same WiFi connection.

Answer (score 0):

From this support [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972).

1. Log on to the Web server computer as an administrator.
2. Click Start, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
3. Double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet Services Manager.
4. Right-click the Web site that you want to configure in the left pane, and then click properties.
5. Click the Web site tab.
6. Type a description for the Web site in the Description box.
7. Type the Internet Protocol (IP) address to use for the Web site or leave the All (Unassigned) default setting.
8. Modify the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) port as appropriate.
9. Click the Home Directory tab.
10. To use a folder on the local computer, click A directory on this computer, and then click Browse to locate the folder that you want to use (your asp.net web site).
11. Click Read to grant read access to the folder (required).
12. Click OK to accept the Web site properties.

Then you can navigate it by your computer name or IP address.  This is assuming the devices you want to use are on the same domain (network).

For instance it could be `http://127.0.0.1/YourSiteName` to get to the site on your local machine.   You can figure out your machine's IP address by running ipconfig from the command prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I can't try it out now because I'm not at work,but I'll try tomorrow and let you know how it went.

Comment: I get this error:The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.

Comment: What authentication are you using in the application?  If it is Windows then you may have to be prompted for a username/password to access the application.